# Understanding the impact of autoloaded packages

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm having difficulty understanding the impact of having packages included (for example with composer), and autoloaded. For example, I'm currently trying to build an API with Lumen and hitting a bunch of roadblocks, because of poor documentation and a small userbase. People have suggested I use Laravel instead and comment out the services/middleware/functionality I wont use. But at the same time, if the packages are being autoloaded, how much of an inpact does that make?

On the surface, I'd think autoloading everything in my vendor directory would lead to a bunch of stuff in memory that would never be used. However, I'd doubt that it works by loading everything (I assume it builds some sort of reference system so when the code is called, it can be executed).

Looking online, it seems that Laravel is only 2-3 times slower than Lumen, though it has far more packages. If I start disabling functionality, I can put that on the lower end, if not much closer. But from a lower level, what impact is loading all the packages in the framework having? How much should I let it impact my decision on what framework to use?

Comment: Autoloading is "lazy" -- it only loads what is needed, at the time it's needed.

Comment: As I imagined, but even lazy, it has to create some sort of internal map, otherwise it wouldn't know what to load, right? Which means more files, more packages, means more stuff in that map. Plus, the more packages, specially inter-related packages, the more stuff loads that I don't know about/control (one part of a package loading other parts)?

Comment: _"it has to create some sort of internal map"_ Not necessarily, depends on the autoloader. Many (most?) autoload implementations build the fully qualified path dynamically at request time. I don't believe composer's autoloader uses a classmap unless you specifically tell it to. (Not 100% sure about that, though.) _"the more stuff loads"_ No, nothing loads until you ask for it.

Comment: Um... how can it build the fully qualified path dynamically? There's no relationship between namespace and directory structure; I guess this is where I'm getting concerned. I'm trying to understand how the mapping works to get any idea of how to understand what resources it uses. And as for more stuff loads, with related packages, specially in a framework, they often call each other. I'm only requesting x, but x requests y and z, whether I need y or z or not.

Comment: _"There's no relationship between namespace and directory structure"_ There should be. See [`PSR-4`](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/).

Comment: _"I'm only requesting x, but x requests y and z, whether I need y or z or not."_ You're trying to solve problems you don't have. It's not an issue. Just code, man. :)

Comment: I have reviewed PSR-4, and I try to keep my code to it, but I've seen various packages that work fine with composer autoloading that don't follow it?

Comment: As to problems I don't have: yah, but I'm trying to understand the underlying systems better so the code I write is better :) If I can understand how packages are brought in, I can recommend and choose frameworks better, decide when things matter and they don't. It doesn't matter for a personal project, but when a new project comes up at work and resources are more important? That knowledge helps.

Comment: If a package doesn't adhere to either `PSR-0` or `PSR-4` then it needs to have a classmap. This is not terribly common however. In any case, it doesn't matter -- if you ever run into a resource issue, it's not going to be because of your autoloader. _"decide when things matter and they don't"_ Yes, this is a good thing. The size of a package's support base and the quality of its documentation are important factors in this decision. How it autoloads is not.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for all the info; like I said, I'm looking at moving away form Lumen, because it's base is so small. So looking at Laravel (which seems more bloated) vs Slim (where I have to do a bunch more work).

Comment: FWIW, I like Slim a lot for APIs. If your API will consist of mostly simple CRUD operations on mapped tables, you might also check out [Apigility](https://apigility.org/).

Comment: I started looking into Slim, but hit road blocks with ORMs/ODMs (I tried Doctrine, can't get it working, tempted to build my own).